# When is https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg expected to recover?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg is down right now. It responds:

```
Internal Server Error

TracError: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/var/lib/gforge/trac/dbs/ros-pkg/log/trac.log'
```

What is the prognosis for its recovery?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12717/when-is-https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg-expected-to-recover?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-01-23**:
Probably better question for the mailing list, but I would have to guess whenever the left-coasters wake up and get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's back now. [mailing list thread](https://code.ros.org/lurker/attach/3@20120123.184533.1e02e550.attach)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1